# Migration failed from htaccess to nginx configuration

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, nginx, mod-rewrite, npm

I'm in process of migration from .htaccess to nginx.conf file but after migration rules doesn't work as I expected.
This is content of .htaccess that I'm gonna migrato to nginx.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

And this is content of nginx.conf that I've migrated:

```
index index.php

location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 break;
}
```

Please let me know what's wrong with this and how can I get nginx conf file works.

Regards. Yuming

Comment: You are missing a `;` from the end of the `index` statement. Also, try replacing the `rewrite` statement with: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri;`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Tried it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `.htaccess` statements perform a similar function to the Nginx `try_files` directive.

Try:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.